# Essential knowledge for making HTML/JavaScript-based games

Tags: web, html5, javascript

I was wondering if any experts out there could share the knowledge and resources of what is necessary to start making games with the latest HTML standards and JavaScript (or what some like to call HTML 5). Are there JavaScript libraries that are essential to the process? Aside from the `<canvas>` tag, what other pieces of HTML do we need to be aware of?

Answer (score 9):

You should be aware of the [Audio](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#audio) and [Video](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#video) tags. [Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) is pretty critical if you need to save a lot of data for saved games etc.

There are already a few Javascript html5 game frameworks, [Akihabara](http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/) is rather popular.

As far as other libraries, [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) and [Functional Javascript](http://github.com/osteele/functional-javascript) are 2 of my favorites.

Comment: what are the strengths of each frameworks? Which one is the simplest, the most robust and with the cleanest code? The word "Functional" in the Functional Javascript -term sounds interesting, what is it really about? Which framework would you suggest to pythonist?

Comment: what does Web Storage provide that a db can't?

Comment: @expiredninja a database would actually be better but web storage is local to the user's machine. No hosting & faster than making ajax calls etc. This answer is (slightly) out of date with the techniques used for modern browser based games.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of frameworks already: [GameQuery](http://gamequery.onaluf.org/) and [Akihabara](http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/), which is a plugin for jQuery to do some game-related activities, like animations, grouping sprites, detect collisions and read player input.

Answer (score 4):

Just to throw more resources out there, check out [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/). It's a very nice SVG drawing and animation library that has a nice API. Don't forget to check out the demos.

Overall, I'd recommend `<canvas>` tags over straight DOM manipulation (e.g. making each sprite its own `<div>` to make hit-testing amazingly simple). It's easy to get DOM manipulation wrong and badly performant, whereas traditional 2d development strategies work well on an HTML canvas.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to some of the game-making frameworks that are out there, you should be aware of the Burst Engine, which is a JS framework for displaying SVG-based animations in an HTML5 Canvas:

http://burst.bocoup.com/

So far I've seen people mention the  and  tags, but there are other DOM things that are vital to JS/HTML game development, including stuff like adding EventListener callbacks to the  element for things like the 'mousemove' and 'mousedown' events. For example, this takes the first canvas element it can find and sets it up so that when you click on the canvas, it calls a function you've defined called "shootAtClick":

document.getElementsByTagName("CANVAS")[0].addEventListener('mousedown', shootAtClick, false);

You can see it in action in [this example](http://tools.bostongamejams.com/akihabara_tutorials/tutx_mouse_controls2/) where I've extended the Akihabara engine to accept basic mouse control. (Press Z to begin, use arrow keys to move, click the mouse to shoot in the direction of the cursor.)

Answer (score 3):

Knowledge of what HTML5 components are supported in what browsers.

Though cross browser compatibility is getting better and more uniform as time goes on some of the newer components are still not supported entirely equally.

Local storage may have some browser specific differences, and for legacy support you'll definitely need a library such as [jStorage](http://github.com/andris9/jStorage) or [YUI Storage Lite](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/storage-lite).

Web sockets as well may have browser specific differences, but [socket.io](http://socket.io/) looks like a promising library that provides a convenient abstraction.

Audio compatibility is a pretty major component that requires different sound files for different browsers: http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/

Chrome has a couple of significant audio bugs, such as [being unable to play short audio files](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=25972), and playing many simultaneous sounds can crash the entire browser.

The main thing is to understand the browser differences, using libraries to abstract and provide legacy support as needed.

Answer (score 1):

HTML and JavaScript are honestly fairly bad platforms for game development, but that won't matter until you've decided on a kind of game.  The answer would be radically different for a first person shooter, an RTS or a puzzle game.

Notice that you're starting to get vague, hand-wavey answers rattling off random technologies that seem neat.  That's a warning sign that you haven't asked a question with a particularly legitimate answer.

You might as well ask what C++ stuff you need to write applications.  That depends.  Tell us more about the project, and you might get a useful answer.

By and on the whole, there's a reason that nearly all web games are still Flash.

Comment: Actually, this "question" was explicitly meant to be vague in order to assess and build up a searchable resource on this site for the curious minds who want to experiment in this development environment.

Comment: I'd agree that the question is vague and the answers all over the place, but disagree that "HTML and[JS] are... bad platforms for game development." Remember Google's Pac-Man doodle? Straight HTML and JS.

I think a certain kind of casual game works pretty well on that platform, and web-using humans already have the runtime. ( =

Comment: @D. Hayes they used Flash for the sound as well.

Comment: Yup! But they had to turn it off during the course of the day because of problems with the Flash runtime in Firefox. No such problems in HTML/JS. I'm just sayin'.

Comment: Wow, pac-man.  Groundbreaking.

There's a reason nobody uses HTML/JS in gaming for anything other than tech demos.

Comment: @Edmundito : If that is how you feel this 'question' should go, it should be marked as CW.

Comment: -1 worthless answer. If your opinion is that web games aren't a good platform then sit down. I don't know why this got so many upvotes, maybe other people share your opinions but it doesn't contribute to answering this question at all.

Comment: -1 good platform or not it's a very widely used platform which makes the question relevant

Comment: "there's a reason that nearly all web games are still Flash" - flash used to be the only way if you ignore the horrors that are Java applets.

Comment: I sense a frustrated Flash developer here. HTML5 is the future, nothing will stop the Flash game prices falling...

Comment: Guys, quit raging out.  The answer was very different in 2010 than it is today in 2014.  I have a bunch of HTML games in store right now.